Run a script when a Hyper-V virtual machine is resumed after save
I'd like to run a PowerShell script within a Hyper-V virtual machine when the VM is re-started (not booted) after been saved. A scheduled task triggered off a specific event maybe but I can't spot anything related about re-start after save in the event logs. There are events written to the Hyper-V host but need the event to be triggered in the VM itself.
With VMware Workstation, this could be achieved using VMware Tools Scripts like resume-vm-default.bat. Not sure if Hyper-V integration services offers anything similar.

Nope, not part of what Hyper-V does. Best you can do is polling in a script running in the background.
System Center has a management system for Hyper-V - that would be a likely place for that.

I suspect you're right. Not found anything inside the VM. So now thinking of capturing the event on the Hyper-V host and running the PowerShell script remotely. Found Invoke-CommandAs which allows a script to be run remotely under the SYSTEM account.
